# Forms CakePhp 1 form multiple tables

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have two controllers partners and deals.

When I add deal there is field partner id and in cakephp this generates a dropdown with all the partners. Is there away that if the user wants to add a new partner they could click a checkbox and add form would appear. Tried adding the partner input boxes and yes this creates new partner but it in the deal table it puts the partner id of the selected partner from the drop down not the new partner.

Deal Veiw

```
<div class="deals form">
<h2>Add New Deal</h2>
<p>Use the form below to fill in the new deals details.</p>
<?php echo $form->create('Deal');?>
    <?php
        echo $cksource->create();
        echo $form->input('title');
        echo $form->input('price');
        echo $form->input('market_price');
        echo $form->input('discount');
        echo $form->input('buy_link');
        echo $form->input('image');

        $config['toolbar'] = array(
            array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-','BulletedList' ),
            array( 'Image', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' )
        );
        ?><label>Deal Highlights</label><?php
        echo $cksource->ckeditor('highlights', array('config'=>$config));
        ?><label>Deal Fine Print</label><?php
        echo $cksource->ckeditor('fine_print', array('config'=>$config));

        echo $form->input('description');
        ?><hr />
        <h3>Partners Details<?php
        echo $form->input('partner_id');
        echo $form->input('Partner.name');
        echo $form->input('Partner.address1');
        echo $form->input('Partner.city');
        echo $form->input('Partner.county');
        echo $form->input('Partner.postcode');
        echo $form->input('city_id');
        ?><hr />
        <h3>Schedule Deal<?php
        echo $form->input('start');
        echo $form->input('end');
    echo $cksource->end();      
    ?>

<?php echo $form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
```

Deal Controller

```
function admin_add() {
        if (!empty($this->data['Partner']['name'])) {
            $this->data['Deal']['partner_id'] = "";
            if ($this->Deal->Partner->saveAll($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'deals', 'action' => 'add'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->Deal->saveAll($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'deals', 'action' => 'add'));
            }
        }
        $partners = $this->Deal->Partner->find('list');

        $cities = $this->Deal->City->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('partners', 'cities'));
    }
```

Any Ideas guys? If you know a better way to do it would be happy to hear it,

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

in controller before saving, check if the partner form is not empty, then empty out the $this->data['Deal']['partner_id'];

Comment: then there will be no partner id linking the deal and the new partner.

Comment: use $this->Deal->Partner->saveAll($this->data) instead of $this->Deal->saveAll($this->data)

Comment: would it be $this->Deal->Partner->create() as well?

Comment: you don't really need create() in this case

Comment: tried this see the code above thats what i have now, still not working

Comment: when I said check if partner form not empty, I meant check if the user enters data in the form: if (!empty($this->data['Partner']['name'])); and make sure you have Partner hasMany Deal relationship

Comment: edited the code agin see the deal controller code above still no luck and partners has got a hasMany relationship with deals :(